# Android / Internal Phone Storage / File Access

Tags: android, file, filesystems

How to get to a file in Android's Internal Storage. Here's a screenshot of the File Manager of Android:

[image]

I want to get to a folder named "csentry".

To figure out the path to csentry, I examined the entire filesystem structure using this code (I'm running my code directly on the device, I have my device connected to my laptop through USB, developer debug mode on, the device is running Android 4.1.1):

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    File rootDirectory = Environment.getRootDirectory();

    Log.d("filez", "-----------------");
    traverse(0, rootDirectory);
    Log.d("filez", "-----------------");
}

private void traverse(int level, File f) {
    if (f != null && f.isDirectory()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            sb.append(".");
        }
        sb.append(f.getName());

        Log.d("traverse", sb.toString());

        File[] f2s = f.listFiles();
        if (f2s != null) {
            for (File f2 : f2s) {
                traverse(level+1, f2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I only get these (I don't see csentry, nor Android, nor LOST.DIR):

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
D/filez﹕ -----------------
D/traverse﹕ system
D/traverse﹕ .app
D/traverse﹕ .bin
D/traverse﹕ .etc
D/traverse﹕ ...tp
D/traverse﹕ ..bluetooth
D/traverse﹕ ..dhcpcd
D/traverse﹕ ...dhcpcd-hooks
D/traverse﹕ ..firmware
D/traverse﹕ ..mddb
D/traverse﹕ ..permissions
D/traverse﹕ ..ppp
D/traverse﹕ ..radvd
D/traverse﹕ ..security
D/traverse﹕ ...cacerts
D/traverse﹕ ..theme
D/traverse﹕ ..updatecmds
D/traverse﹕ ..wifi
D/traverse﹕ .fonts
D/traverse﹕ .framework
D/traverse﹕ .lib
D/traverse﹕ ..drm
D/traverse﹕ ..egl
D/traverse﹕ ..hw
D/traverse﹕ ..modules
D/traverse﹕ ..soundfx
D/traverse﹕ ..ssl
D/traverse﹕ ...engines
D/traverse﹕ .media
D/traverse﹕ ..audio
D/traverse﹕ ...alarms
D/traverse﹕ ...notifications
D/traverse﹕ ...ringtones
D/traverse﹕ ...ui
D/traverse﹕ ..images
D/traverse﹕ ..video
D/traverse﹕ .mobile_toolkit
D/traverse﹕ .res
D/traverse﹕ ..images
D/traverse﹕ ..sound
D/traverse﹕ .tts
D/traverse﹕ ..lang_pico
D/traverse﹕ .usr
D/traverse﹕ ..icu
D/traverse﹕ ..idc
D/traverse﹕ ..keychars
D/traverse﹕ ..keylayout
D/traverse﹕ ..share
D/traverse﹕ ...bmd
D/traverse﹕ ...zoneinfo
D/traverse﹕ ..srec
D/traverse﹕ ...en-US
D/traverse﹕ .vendor
D/traverse﹕ ..bin
D/traverse﹕ ..lib
D/traverse﹕ ...drm
D/traverse﹕ ...egl
D/traverse﹕ ...hw
D/traverse﹕ ..pittpatt
D/traverse﹕ ...models
D/traverse﹕ ....detection
D/traverse﹕ .....multi_pose_face_landmark_detectors.7
D/traverse﹕ ......left_eye-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-r0-ri20.lg_32
D/traverse﹕ ......nose_base-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-r0-ri20.lg_32
D/traverse﹕ ......right_eye-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-r0-ri20.lg_32-2
D/traverse﹕ .....yaw_roll_face_detectors.6
D/traverse﹕ ......head-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-r0-ri30.4a-v24
D/traverse﹕ ......head-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-rn30-ri30.5-v24
D/traverse﹕ ......head-y0-yi45-p0-pi45-rp30-ri30.5-v24
D/traverse﹕ ....recognition
D/traverse﹕ .....face.face.y0-y0-22-b-N
D/traverse﹕ .xbin
D/traverse﹕ .secro
D/traverse﹕ .lost+found
D/filez﹕ -----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something Like this.

### Check For If directory Exists

```
File file = new File(directory);
if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
      // Do something you have found your directory
```

that should do it.. Hope I helped..

I Would suggest you to read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). These are the Documentations on File. They will help u in the near Future.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it...: I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); instead.

Strange, because this phone doesn't have SD Card. Apparently (maybe in this particular phone only?) internal storage is seen as SD card.

Anyway... Case closed :)

```
D/filez﹕ -----------------
D/traverse﹕ sdcard0
D/traverse﹕ .LOST.DIR
D/traverse﹕ ..android_secure
D/traverse﹕ .Android
D/traverse﹕ ..data
D/traverse﹕ ...com.google.android.youtube
D/traverse﹕ ....files
D/traverse﹕ ...com.google.android.videos
D/traverse﹕ ....files
D/traverse﹕ .....Movies
D/traverse﹕ ...com.android.gallery3d
D/traverse﹕ ....cache
D/traverse﹕ ...com.google.android.apps.maps
D/traverse﹕ ....testdata
D/traverse﹕ ....debug
D/traverse﹕ ....cache
D/traverse﹕ ...com.android.browser
D/traverse﹕ ....files
D/traverse﹕ .Notifications
D/traverse﹕ .csentry
D/traverse﹕ ..IMSS
D/traverse﹕ .Pictures
D/traverse﹕ ..Screenshots
D/traverse﹕ .DCIM
D/traverse﹕ ..browser-photos
D/filez﹕ -----------------
```